# how to delete extra files from backup with shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, backup

A backup Shell Script

```
#!/bin/bash

backdest=/home/backup
date=$(date "+%F")

backupall="$backdest/arch-full-$date.tgz"
backuphome="$backdest/jary_p-$date.tgz"

tar -czpvf $backupall / --exclude=/home/* --exclude=/mnt/* --exclude=/media/* \
                        --exclude=/proc/* --exclude=/sys/* --exclude=/dev/*   \
                        --exclude=/tmp/* --exclude=/lost+found/*

tar -czpvf $backuphome /home/jary_p
```

Several(5) times later
there are Serveral(10) files in  /home/backup

```
$ls /home/backup
backup.sh
arch-full-2011-05-13.tgz
arch-full-2011-05-25.tgz
arch-full-2011-06-01.tgz
arch-full-2011-06-09.tgz
arch-full-2011-06-11.tgz
jary_p-2011-05-13.tgz
jary_p-2011-05-25.tgz
jary_p-2011-06-01.tgz
jary_p-2011-06-09.tgz
jary_p-2011-06-11.tgz
```

How can I just keep the lastest 3 fiels(6) and delete extra files?
thanks
and, apologize my poor English.

Answer (score 1):

```
ls -t $backdest/jary_p-*.tgz | tac | tail -n +3 | xargs rm
```

And repeat with $backupall's glob

Comment: Why use `tac`, won't `ls -tr` do the same?

Comment: Sure.  You could also use `ls | sort -r | tail -n +3` in case someone has `touched` the file since it was created.  There is more than one way.

Comment: I should have mentioned originally that I'm always looking for ways to remove processes ;-), but as you say, there's more than one way. Cheers.

Comment: @Auston Jary: Always possible.  My example was keeping the last three files of each backup type.  Perhaps you can explain more about how this doesn't meet your needs?

Comment: `ls | sort -r | tail -n +3` or `ls -t $backdest/jary_p-*.tgz | tac | tail -n +3 `  just display the lastest 3(6) files or backup.sh. But I want keep it...

Comment: @Auston: If it is returning the wrong "side" of the files, then you can remove the tac. However, I strongly question this. I suspect you may be misreading something. Can you paste the output of ls -lt | tac and ls -t | tac | tail -n +3? Also, tail --version (mine is GNU 8.12).

Answer (score 0):

I have found how to solved it

```
ls -htr *.tgz|head -n -6 | xargs rm
```

Comment: I do not recommend that approach.  This deletes the last six files irregardless.  However, if you run that twice, you will be very unhappy.  Using my technique of taking off the files you want to save will be better.  ANd I question why -h is in there.